# common terms query not fetch data

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch version is 2.4,

I am using this query but this is giving blank array.
any one help me to find where i was wrong.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/stores/store/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "query": {
  "common": {
   "body": {
    "query": "donald trump for president",
     "cutoff_frequency": 0.1
     }
    }
  }
}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The query looks ok. Can you show your mapping, and an example doc you expect to find with this query?

Comment: curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/new_stopwords/' -d '{"settings" : {"index" : {"number_of_shards" : 6, "number_of_replicas" : 1 }},"mappings" : {"new_stopword" : {"_all":{ "enabled": true  },"properties":{"title" : { "type" : "text", "boost" : 2 },"description" : { "type" : "text" }}}}}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're querying a field that doesn't exist (`body`). You should query a field that exists in your mapping, or `_all`:

```
{
 "query": {
  "common": {
   "_all": {
    "query": "donald trump for president",
     "cutoff_frequency": 0.1
     }
    }
  }
}
```